# How to trigger react for radio input in Bigcommerce optimized checkout

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bigcommerce

I am trying to select a specific shipping option in Bigcommerce optimized checkout with jquery for one customer group only. This works with the old style checkout. In the optimized checkout, the script selects the correct radio button but does not update the shipping cost.

```js
if ($('.shippingOptions-container .form-checklist-header--selected:contains("UK Standard")').length) {
  $('.shippingOptions-container li:first-child').css("display", "none");
    $('.shippingOptions-container li input').prop('checked', false);   
    $('.shippingOptions-container li:last-child input:radio').prop('checked', true); // Select last option
    
  //Need to trigger react here?
}
```

For reference, here is HTML for checkout shipping options:

```html
<div class="shippingOptions-container form-fieldset">
  <div class="loadingOverlay-container">
    <ul class="form-checklist optimizedCheckout-form-checklist">
      <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item">
        <div class="form-checklist-header">
          <div class="form-field">
            <input name="shippingOptionIds.614eb9138f512" class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox" id="shippingOptionRadio-614eb9138f512-0c4f74daf3665ba298ee29fce61d0e38" type="radio" value="0c4f74daf3665ba298ee29fce61d0e38" checked="">
            <label for="shippingOptionRadio-614eb9138f512-0c4f74daf3665ba298ee29fce61d0e38" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">               <div class="shippingOptionLabel">
                 <div class="shippingOption shippingOption--alt">
                    <span class="shippingOption-desc">UK Standard</span>
                    <span class="shippingOption-price">£5.00</span>
                 </div>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item form-checklist-item--selected optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item--selected">
        <div class="form-checklist-header form-checklist-header--selected">
          <div class="form-field">
            <input name="shippingOptionIds.614eb9138f512" class="form-checklist-checkbox optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-checkbox" id="shippingOptionRadio-614eb9138f512-6c03494e9505e15542ccfada6b0ac866" type="radio" value="6c03494e9505e15542ccfada6b0ac866">
            <label for="shippingOptionRadio-614eb9138f512-6c03494e9505e15542ccfada6b0ac866" class="form-label optimizedCheckout-form-label">
              <div class="shippingOptionLabel">
                <div class="shippingOption shippingOption--alt">
                  <span class="shippingOption-desc">Express</span>
                  <span class="shippingOption-price">£20.00</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot change any HTML as this is part of the checkout controlled by Bigcommerce.

How do I trigger the event so it updates the same as a manual mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
myElement.prop('checked', true);
```

Try:

```
myElement.click();
```

The former sets the value of the HTML input, but React in this context does not care about that. Using click() simulates the user clicking--it fires the onClick() handler which is the magic you need for React to see this change.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I tried this before and it makes no difference.

Comment: I did actually test the .click() strategy in a BigCommerce Checkout form before posting that. Hmmm... Check out this screencast: https://vimeo.com/654366197/6a2742c6cf

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanatory video. I had tried .click() using Jquery previously to no avail. Jquery selects the input but does not trigger React. However, using Javascript works fine. I still don't understand why there is any difference but I'm happy the problem is at last solved and much simpler than updating consignments via the API! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this exact thing pretty extensively and have not found an answer on how to trigger a React state change in the BigCommerce checkout app.

In the end, the approach I have had to take was to update the data using the [storefront checkout API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/storefront/checkouts) and then to trigger a page refresh to ensure the React state matched with the checkout data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looking again at the checkout process in developer tools it seems the update is made via the API but I think there has to be a way to simulate a simple selection/click event to trigger the event listener.